# How to undo effects of DDU

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, display-driver, adware

I recently called Nvidia asking how to manually remove my graphics driver and all other previously installed drivers and any other lingering folders and registry entries. I should have never called them, nor should I have listened to the advice they gave me. They recommended a program called Display Driver Uninstaller, DDU for short. I thought to myself when I heard this "awesome, a program that does it all for me, and Nvidia is recommending it, what could go wrong?".

After running DDU and installing the latest Nvidia driver, my PC began to run like crap. My PC has been running flawlessly for years, but now My login time has increased dramatically. The program MotioninJoy that i have used without a hitch for years now has extra ads injected into it and also is very laggy and is doings things that it didn't used to. Also multiple other actions hang for a sec whereas they used to run instantly, for example left clicking on the volume icon in on the task bar.  The only two bits of software, or anything for that matter, that I have installed on my PC while it still was running flawlessly was DDU and the new Nvidia driver. I don't see Nvidia as the likely culprit as I have never had trouble with any of their previous drivers.

Does anyone know any way I can make it as if I had never run DDU, besides system restore? I unfortunately do not have a backup. I am running Windows 7.

**Here's the email I received from Nvidia containing the links I used.**

> Hi Cameron,
>
> Thank you for contacting NVIDIA Customer Care. It was a pleasure
>   talking to you.
>
> This email is with reference to the telephonic conversation we had
>   today regarding the issue you were facing with Nvidia drivers.
>
> Based on our telephonic conversation, please follow the steps provided
>   below :-
>
> Please uninstall the driver completely using DDU :-
>   http://www.guru3d.com/files-get/display-driver-uninstaller-download,20.html
>   - (Perform the steps in normal mode)
>   - Select NVIDIA on top and Put a check mark on all the NVIDIA components near the NVIDIA logo.
>   - Now click on Clean and Restart (Highly Recommended)
>   - Once the computer restarts and goes to the Windows, please follow the steps below
>
> -Download the driver version :- http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/112195/en-us
>
> - Once the installer wizard begin, accept the license agreement.
> - Select "Custom (Advanced)" install option and then click Next.
> - Put a checkmark in the "Perform clean install" option and then click Next.
> - Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the installation.
>
> If there are any questions or concerns, feel free to contact me.
>
> I look forward for your reply to assist you better.
>
> Regards
>
> Manojit Choudhury NVIDIA Customer Care

Comment: Why did you opt for it in the first place? Where did you download the program from and where did you download the Nvidia drivers from? Reinstall the system instead of doing a restore would be another option but I guess that would also be not possible? Otherwise there is a plethora of Malware cleaning utilities available. Did you look for suspicious process and try to kill them/uninstall them?

Comment: Re-installing is possible but definitely my last choice, as I have many custom firewall rules, host file changes, and lots of programs installed. I use task manager to kill processes all the time, but I don't really know what to look for unless I have something already in mind. So I'm not sure how to identify the possibly rogue process. Is there a list of minimal required processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you download the program from? It is most likely you got it from the wrong source and got a virus. I have used DDU extensively over the years and never had problems with it.

Download [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) and run a thorough scan. In additional, check your task manager for suspicious processes.

Looking at motion joy, practically all the screenshots of it appear to show it having ads, so that does not come as a surprise.

You can also check and see if Windows is trying to automatically install some drivers and disable that.

Comment: I edited the post to reflect the links I used to download. I'll have to install malwarebytes and give it a go. I've never had virus software installed before nor do I usually even need it because I am always careful about the files that I open. I have never had a virus before on my current machine in 3 years of use. I just thought nvidia would have my back so I let my guard down.

Comment: also I have been using motion in joy for over 5 years, 3 years on my current PC and the ads that are there now were never there before. If you have never used the program, then you really don't have the credence to be surprised or unsurprised about the ads I'm talking about, that's even why I said extra ads, not just ads.

Comment: @Skateguy "Correlation does not imply causation" - You using DDU didn't change the behavior of Motion Joy.